# Key derivation for secp256k1

Tags: security, cryptography, bitcoin, elliptic-curve

In order to deterministically generate a new secp256k1 key from existing key, is it safe to just take the sha256 result from old key and use it as entropy to generate a new secp256k1 key? Using this method, I can get the derived key as long as I have oldPrivKeyHex.

```
  const ec = new EC('secp256k1');
  const keyHash = shajs('sha256')
    .update(oldPrivKeyHex)
    .digest();
  var newKey = ec.genKeyPair({ entropy: keyHash });
```

lib src: 
https://github.com/indutny/elliptic

Comment: Can you please say that what is the advantage/application of getting derived key from an old key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but I would do it differently. I'd use the hash over the other key (or even better, the result of a key derivation function or KDF) and then directly use it for the `fromPrivate` method or to use the `KeyPair` constructor with the private key as parameter.

The reason is that the random number generator hasn't been precisely specified. If anything happens with the handling of the random number generation then you might suddenly get a different key.

The KDF or hash method will already make sure that the entropy is compressed, so the random number generator isn't required anymore. I'd of course rather use SHA-512 or SHA-256 (in that order) than a hash algorithm that provides less than 256 bits.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you suggest to use oldPrivKeyHex as input to some KDF to get a new private key, and use it for "fromPrivate method" to get new key pair, right? If so, any recommend KDF? and how can I make sure the result of KDF is a valid secp256k1 private key? Thanks a lot !!!!

Comment: HKDF is nice, but KDF1 is probably easier to use. If you cannot find a KDF, then just use the hash. The private key is a random in between 0 and N, the order of the curve. But the implementation will already make sure of that, so just feed it pseudo-random data that is about the same size as the EC key size (preferably somewhat larger, of course).

Comment: You may also want to check out ratchets wrt key renewal.